# Some basic properties of independence number of graph

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics, extremal-graph-theory

Suppose that $G=(V,E)$ is a simple graph on $n$ vertices and consider $\alpha(G)$ - independence number of $G$.

I have some questions related with quantity $\alpha(G)$.

1. Am I right that $\alpha(G)\neq0$ because for any $v\in V$ you can consider $\{v\}$ as an independent set, right?
2. If $\alpha(G)=1$, then $G$ is a complete graph on $n$ vertices, right?

Comment: Yes and yes. For (2), ask yourself what happens if a graph is not complete.
You must get $u$ and $v$ that are not adjacent. But then $\{u,v\}$ is independent.

Comment: @BrandonduPreez, Probably you mean that $u\neq v$, right?

Comment: Yes. So have two different vertices that are not adjacent.